# Is there a way to send a message to people when they Like your Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'd like to give a special "thank you" message to people who Like our Facebook Page.
Sort of like a a "confirmation message" you'd get when signing up for an Email Newsletter.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a cron job which actually runs an sms sending api or EMAIL api when ever user likes your page. 
But as of now there is not Facebook Internal API that provides this feature.